# Running 'node' in cmd prompt throws error

Tags: node.js

When i try to execute the command 'node' in my command prompt i am facing issue. I have node version 12 and npm version 6 installed in my machine.

error:

> read EINVAL at TTY.onStreamRead node

Comment: Try downgrading to node 10, It could be a build issue that might be fixed in next version. It seems to be an issue associated with libuv that gives us async IO

Comment: Refer to [ticket #9542](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/9542) in node.js repo. I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @PrivateOmega. But the issue still seems to exist